# FLASK_APP variable don't work even it's in .env

Tags: python, flask, environment-variables

I have installed `python-dotenv==0.6.5`

And I put `FLASK_APP` in `.env` file

```
DEBUG=True
FLASK_ENV=development
FLASK_APP=flasky.py
```

But it shows this error when I run `flask run`

```
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]

Error: Could not locate Flask application. You did not provide the FLASK_APP environment variable.

For more information see http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/quickstart/
```

But if I `export FLASK_APP=flasky.py` , it works well.

I also tried to put `FLASK_APP=flasky.py` in `.flaskenv` file, but I didn't work :(

All other env variables are loaded well. Thanks

Comment: Since the code using `python-dotenv` is in the flask module (I'm guessing that's where you have your call to `load_dotenv()`, how would Flask know to use it before knowing which application to load?

Comment: I tried .flaskenv file also, can't we use .flaskenv with .env together?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was FLASK version.
I updated it using `pip install --upgrade Flask`
Thanks!

Comment: it didn't helped me